# trying to start AptanaStudio3 but keep geting an error: Java exit code 13

Tags: java, aptana

Actually there are other solutions related to this but they don't seam to solve the problem any one know a less complicated way to fix this ?

[image: error]

Comment: You should list the solutions tried that **didn't** work so they aren't suggested again.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the problem is the usage of a 64bit jdk, when aptana needs a 32 bit jdk

Is your -vm argument correct? Are you pointing to a valid 32bit jdk?

Comment: sorry wats -vm argument

Comment: -vm tells aptana where to find the jdk.. In your screenshot is pointing to ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe

This comes from eclipse.ini or aptana.ini (located at the root folder of aptana). Check the file and make sure you provide a valid path

Answer (score 0):

1. Install 32-bit version of java, (you can have both[32-bit 64-bit] of java and multiple versions of java on same computer)
2. Go to installed location of 32 bit java 
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` copy the file path of bin directory.
3. Paste path in environment variables. (For adding path plz 
   Visit https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
4. If again not working install nodeJs 32bit